# Subtract values from two columns in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

There are two columns and i want to subtract them. I am trying to sum [payment] column then subtracting it from [total_bill] column. Below but is my code and it gives me error that it Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

```
SELECT SUM((bill_record.total_bill)-SUM(invoice_payments.payment)) AS [LEFT AMOUNT]
```

Comment: In actual code i have used FROM, It is just a a specific part of .

Comment: Edit the question add some sample data & desired result would helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use group by but also you probably just want to sum the payments and subtract those against the single total bill.

```
SELECT bill_record.total_bill - SUM(invoice_payments.payment) AS [LEFT AMOUNT] 
FROM bill_record INNER JOIN invoice_payments ON bill_record.PKColumn = invoice_payments.FKColumn 
WHERE bill_record.PKColumn = @billId
GROUP BY bill_record.total_bill
```

---

Note that the group by here works because you are also filtering in the WHERE clause. If you want to get the results for multiple bills you would also group by a unique bill identifier and have it be returned in the SELECT.

```
SELECT bill_record.PKColumn AS BillId, bill_record.total_bill - SUM(invoice_payments.payment) AS [LEFT AMOUNT] 
FROM bill_record INNER JOIN invoice_payments ON bill_record.PKColumn = invoice_payments.FKColumn 
GROUP BY bill_record.PKColumn, bill_record.total_bill
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem want one `sum` instead of two :

```
SELECT SUM(bill_record.total_bill - invoice_payments.payment) AS [LEFT AMOUNT]
FROM . . .
```

Comment: First i want to sum [invoice_payments.payment] then i want to subtract it from [bill_record.total_bill]

Answer (score 0):

in your request you select items from what .... 
the request should be like

```
SELECT SUM((bill_record.total_bill)-SUM(invoice_payments.payment)) AS [LEFT AMOUNT] FROM YOUR TABLE NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(bill_record.total_bill)-SUM(invoice_payments.payment) AS [LEFT AMOUNT]
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using `SUM` aggregate function so you have to use `group by` clause properly

and number of selection column must on group by clause

```
SELECT SUM((bill_record.total_bill)-SUM(invoice_payments.payment)) AS [LEFT AMOUNT]
```

the of of error can be in group by clause number of column other wise your query should work